# How to manually delete Safari's DNS cache?

Tags: macos, safari, big-sur, dns

Develop > Empty caches (cmd alt e) isn't clearing Safari's DNS cache.

I made some changes to `/etc/hosts` and those changes are reflected in all my other browsers, and `ping` and `getent hosts`, but Safari still loads the previous website.

I have also tried `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` and `sudo dscacheutil --flushcache` and neither help Safari forget the previous address.

Comment: just try restarting

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is isolate your browser from search engines.

- [Cannot block site z1.fm from etc hosts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431950/cannot-block-site-z1-fm-from-etc-hosts)

Next you might need to check for VPN like iCloud Private Relay. There are a handful questions here with [some variations on the theme of blocking hosts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/373317/5472) via file overrides and when it’s time for a reboot after testing.

I like to test this with a text file. You can quit the browser and use commands like

```
nslookup this.web.site
open http://this.web.site 
nslookup apple.stackexchange.com
open https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/436458/5472
```

And then retest flushing the dns cache to determine if you are getting a DNS lookup or a web search engine lookup or it’s just using history or cached / pinned / history of previous web site data to jump start things.

Comment: I don't understand, what should I do? What does it mean "isolate browser from search engines" The issue exists on VPN and not on VPN.

Comment: Isolate means to make the changes in the answer I linked - all of them. Then to retest one specific address. What site can’t you block @theonlygusti ? Did you turn off all VPN and private relay as well?

Comment: Do you want help scripting the lookups? @theonlygusti